# Flow: How to filter for a type from a set of union types

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I am tring to filter for a specific type of object from a list of union types. Here is my attempt so far.

```
/* @flow */

type Human = {|
  name: string
|};

type Droid = {|
  model: string
|};

type LivingThings = {
   things: [Human | Droid]
}

const getHumans = (livingThings: LivingThings): Human[] => {
    return livingThings.things.filter((thing) => {
       return 'name' in thing;
    })
}
```

However this complains of an error as per this link: [Link](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgASArgLYCGAdmALxgDeAPqmGJeaXgFxgDOGAJwCWlAOapGAXwDc6bPjAARAXCEATWg2atScNXhg9+wsRJlzcBADJCAbiNEAVABYPem+i1YZXY3jwBtEgpqRiUVdQBdVEl0AGM4Sn4wUTwMYKp3OgAKGDsHFzceG3sxQr8ASh4MygDI2gA+Bi9WATTiAWo80qdfUV4AOh83AaghGAw8AWzs4bEKxubWZdb2zrAAcnZODbARMDnRWRXJCpigA)

> return livingThings.things.filter((thing) => {
>                  ^ Cannot return `livingThings.things.filter(...)` because property `model` is missing in `Human` [1](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgASArgLYCGAdmALxgDeAPqmGJeaXgFxgDOGAJwCWlAOapGAXwDc6bPjAARAXCEATWg2atScNXhg9+wsRJlzcBADJCAbiNEAVABYPem+i1YZXY3jwBtEgpqRiUVdQBdVEl0AGM4Sn4wUTwMYKp3OgAKGDsHFzceG3sxQr8ASh4MygDI2gA+Bi9WATTiAWo80qdfUV4AOh83AaghGAw8AWzs4bEKxubWZdb2zrAAcnZODbARMDnRWRXJCpigA) but exists in `Droid` [2] in arr

Comment: Are you able to cast to `any[]` first? See [example](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgASArgLYCGAdmALxgDeAPqmGJeaXgFxgDOGAJwCWlAOapGAXwDc6bPjAARAXCEATWg2atScNXhg9+wsRJlzcBADJCAbiNEAVABYPem+i1YZXY3jwBtEgpqRiUVdQBdVEl0AGM4Sn4wUTwMYKp3OgAKGDsHFzceG3sxQr8ASh4MygDI2gA+Bi9WATTiAWpc-LLfUV4AOh83AaghGAw8AWzs4bEKxubWZdb2zrAAcnZODbARMDnRWRXJKrAqLDqKmKA)

Comment: No we are using `strict` mode, so can't use `any.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Flow [does not refine types with filter](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1414). The linked issue is quite old and it has been on the roadmap for quite some time. As suggested above you can cast to any or use `$ExpectError` to create a locally unsafe function. Alternatively, you can use an imperative loop approach:

```js
const res: Human[] = [];
for (thing of livingThings.things) {
  if (typeof thing.name === 'string') {
    res.push(thing)
  }
}
return res;
```

Or create a useful helper function `mapMaybe` that you can reuse in many other cases:

```js
function mapMaybe<A, B>(f: A => ?B, xs: A[]): B[] {
  // $ExpectError or alternatively write loop here
  return xs.map(f).filter(notUndefinedOrNull);
}

mapMaybe(thing => {
  if (typeof thing.name === 'string') {
    return thing;
  }
  return null;
}, livingThings.things);
```